# Unexpected value returned from sizeof

Tags: c

I allocate an array `a` 4 blocks (each is of size `sizeof(int)`). Then I try to print the length of the array with the following code:

```
int main() {
    int *a = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    printf("%d", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Once I run this code, it prints `2`, although I expected `4`. Why is it?

Comment: `sizeof(a)` returns the size of a pointer, not the size of the allocated memory

Comment: `a` is a pointer, `sizeof(a)` is the size of a pointer (to int), `sizeof(a[0])` is the size of an `int`. Compare with `int a[4]; sizeof a / sizeof *a;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a magical "how much space did I `malloc` into this pointer" function. The idiom you're using only works with real arrays, not pointers being dereferenced as arrays. Here, it means `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`, which is clearly not useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking that `a` is an array of 4 elements.
But it is not.  It is a pointer.

I'm deducing that your system is a 64-bit system with 8-byte pointers.

So `sizeof(a)` is 8.  And `sizeof(a[0])` is `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes.

So the expression becomes `8/4 == 2`.

---

If you had declared `a` as `int a[4];`
Then you would indeed get 4 for a result.